# Prove that the divergence of gradient of a vector equal zero if the divergence is zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensor-products

Let $ \overrightarrow v=v_i \overrightarrow e_i \thinspace,\nabla \cdot v=0$ , show that $\nabla \cdot(\nabla v)=0 $

Gradient is defined as : 
$$\nabla v=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j} \otimes e_j=\frac{\partial (v_ie_i)}{\partial x_j}\otimes e_j=\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}e_i\otimes e_j$$

Divergence is defined as:

$$\nabla \cdot v=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}\cdot e_j=\frac{\partial (v_ie_i)}{\partial x_j}\cdot e_j=\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(e_i\cdot e_j)= \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(\delta_{ij})=\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}$$
I got confused abut proving this in Einstein notation so It would be great if this made clear.

Comment: Are you sure you're stating the problem correctly? $\nabla \cdot (\nabla v)$ is the vector laplacian, which need not be $0$. Now the divergence of the curl of a vector field, or the curl of the gradient are both $0$.

Comment: The idea is to get gradient of a divergence from that and then we use the assumption that the the divergence is zero to get zero. Could you get to that identity in Einstein notation which doesn’t seems to be easy

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. In the picture you posted, what is $A$?

Comment: Also I misspoke above. I meant the scalar Laplacian

Comment: A is a vector as on wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90418/discussion-between-farhan-and-joe).